# php read & write from file at the same time

Tags: php, file

Basically I have an XML file to populate data with and I will have a cron (**in PHP**) that updates it every 5 minutes.  But at the same time, I will have users accessing this file all the time (and I'm talking about thousands of users).

When I tried a script myself by writing 2million text lines in a .txt file and reading it at the same time, of course the `file_get_contents()` was getting the current text in the .txt file and does not wait for it to end and get the contents when it's finished. So what I did is, I write to a temporary file and then rename it to the original .txt file. The renaming process on my PC takes up 0.003 seconds (calculated using `microtime()`).

Do you think this is a suitable solution or there will be users which will end up having an error that the file does not exists?

Comment: Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: the XML is populated from a DB of course :) - in 5minutes I would have thousands of DB calls which I would like to reduce them to 1 - it's basically caching the result which is fine for 5 minutes

Comment: thousands db calls in 5 minutes sounds perfectly manageable. Also, you can still add caching to prevent the roundtrip.

Comment: [memcached](http://memcached.org/) is your friend!

Comment: `mv`ing a file on a unix filesystem is atomic, so this would be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is not suitable.. You have to lock the file in this 0.003 microseconds.

A very simple way is a *flag*

For example create file called isReplacing

After replacing is done, delete file isReplacing

When a user wants the file say in `getfile.php`

---

```
 while(file_exists("isReplacing"))
 {}
 //NOW echo file_get_contents()
```

---

```
 //BETTER:
 if(file_exists("isReplacing"))
 {
      //GET DATA FROM DATABASE
 }
 else
 {
      //ECHO THE FILE
 }
```

**NOTE** this is a dumb way but I just want to demonstrate

Comment: what do you think if I delete the file every 5 minutes & rebuild it and if the file does not exists, just get the data from the DB.